# TestStand Sequence Editor launches with "No Steps Selected"

Tags: teststand

My TestStand environment (Windows 10, TestStand 32bit 2019.f4) had been working perfectly until this morning.  When I attempted to launch the Sequence Editor by clicking on its icon in the task bar,  the editor launched into a state that indicates "No Steps Selected"  In the Text indicator box at bottom of window.  On the center of the window there is a similar message displayed: "There are no steps selected.".  (See image at bottom)

I also attempted to open the editor by clicking on the sequence file that I wanted to edit, with the same results.

In desperation, I also removed the TestStand application using Add remove programs, and re-intalled using NI Package Manager.   Same results occurred when opening the Sequence Editor.

I have not seen these conditions before today.  What does this indicate, and how can I escape out of it?

For a ***normal start*** up when opening Sequence Editor I see this:

[image]

I am seeing this ***abnormal start***:

[image]